# NMaximize simple function

Tags: performance-tuning, mathematical-optimization, maximize

I am trying to solve a maximisation using Mathematica. The objective function, though involved, can be broken down into many simpler terms. One of these terms is `-x \log[x]`.

However,

```
NMaximize[-x Log[x], x]
```

does not work, i.e. Mathematica just returns this as the output. How can I force an evaluation? The constraint for `x` is the following: `0<=x<=1`, but even the unoptimised version does not work.

Comment: I don't have this problem. `NMaximize[-x Log[x], x]` returns `{0.367879, {x -> 0.367879}}` and `Maximize...`  gives `{E^(-1), {x -> E^(-1)}}`

Comment: Strange! What version do you have? I'm working with v12.1.0.0 but I don't suspect this is the issue. `Maximize` works as required, but after a refresh `NMaximize` returns `The function value 0.155424 -2.60455\ I is not a real number at {x} = {-0.8290525091498482`}`.

Comment: Seems to work if I force x positive: `NMaximize[{-x Log[x], x >= 0}, x]`

Comment: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KG2Es.png) for v12.2.0 on Win7-x64.

Comment: In 13.3.1 on Windows 19 `NMaximize[-x Log[x], x]` results in `{0.367879, {x -> 0.367879}}`.